# using "child" pages or iframes or other within php

Tags: php, iframe

trying to figure out how to best display a bunch of information on a "mother" page.

When I enter the first page, which is populated based on a GET method for a specific "id". on this page, I want to have an area where the user can click on either a link or button or other which will display a subsection in a single location. These pages will need to display the appropriate information based on data located on the page.

Would the best way just to be to create an iframe?

I'm unclear, as to how I best get this information to change appropriately (i'm still quite new to this process).

would I continue to use the GET method still on the "child" page; Do I also need to use a POST method somewhere?

any guidance would be great.

Comment: generally iframes are not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is to use ajax to populate that div.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've never used ajax so I will do some searching on that...